# Xamarin forms - Update an image source's size in the code

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to be able to edit an image's source size in the code and not in the xaml file so I can handle the display when the image must be `null`.

```cs
using Pokedex.Src.Model.Pokemon.Type;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Pokedex.Src.ValueConverters
{
    class TypeToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            if (value.GetType().Equals(typeof(TYPE)) && (TYPE) value != TYPE.UNKNOWN)
                return GetTypeImageResource((TYPE) value);
            return null;
        }

        private ImageSource GetTypeImageResource(TYPE type) {
            ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource($"Pokedex.Resources.Types.{type.ToString()}.png");
            // HERE EDIT IMAGE SOURCE SIZE
            return imageSource;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use `BindableProperty.Create` but it doesn't change the image size in the screen even though something is happening in the code

```cs
private ImageSource GetTypeImageResource(TYPE type) {
    ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource($"Pokedex.Resources.Types.{type.ToString()}.png");
    BindableProperty bp = BindableProperty.Create("WidthRequest", typeof(int), typeof(ImageSource));
    var wr = imageSource.GetValue(bp); // = 0
    imageSource.SetValue(bp, 48);
    var wr2 = imageSource.GetValue(bp); // = 48
    return imageSource;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by when the image must be null?

Comment: I want the image tag (in the xaml file) to not have the new size properties if its source is null. Thats why I am asking if its possible to change an image source size from the code

Comment: Sorry, I does not get it. I think size of Image tag has noting to do with the image source. Can you add your xaml code or a photo to describe it?